# How to use a link with different url on diffrent page

Tags: javascript, php

I have these links

```
<li class=" "><a href="#who-are-we">Who are we </a></li>
<li class=" "><a href="#how-it-works">How it Works </a></li>
<li class=" "><a href="#what-to-expect">What to expect</a></li>
```

My home page url is   abcd.com
Home page have some data according to `#` tag. The `#` show a scroll down only for home page. when i click on any link then url change in    `abcd.com/#who-are-we`  and scroller point that section on home page,

But i want one thing.

When i will go on any other page as like products page or contact us page then the click action of these links go on about us page. Will you please tell me how can i set a conndition for url in php

Comment: So you want those links to do what exactly when you are on your Products or Contact page? Link back to your index or act like anchor links and link to a portion of the Products and/or Contact page?

Comment: when i am on product or contact page then these links action go on about us page. And when i am on homepage then the action perform as code shows upper

Comment: So .... on your index you want tag type url and in your other pages you want to link to about_us page ?

Comment: @AshuGarg seriously?

Answer (score -1):

You should look at the difference between named Anchors and links to other pages.

You can combine the page AND the named anchor like this:

```
<a href="contact.php#ABC">go to contact page to anchor ABC</a>
```

Here an example:

1. named-anchors: first 3 `<a href>`'s point to a location in this document
2. links: other 2 `<a href>`'s point to other pages...

That should do the trick.

```
<ul>
    <li>About us:
        <ul>
        <li class=" "><a href="about-us.php#who-are-we">Who are we </a></li>
        <li class=" "><a href="about-us.php#how-it-works">How it Works </a></li>
        <li class=" "><a href="about-us.php#what-to-expect">What to expect</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.php">Products Page</a></li>
</ul>

<a name="who-are-we">
    <h2>Who are we</h2>
    <p>Blah<br>blah<br>blaah<br>...</p>

<a name="how-it-works">
    <h2>how-it-works</h2>
    <p>Blah<br>blah<br>blaah<br>...</p>

<a name="what-to-expect">
    <h2>what-to-expect</h2>    
    <p>Blah<br>blah<br>blaah<br>...</p>
```

Comment: Thanx for reply Cagy,

Comment: But my question was difrent. i was asking that when i will on another page expect on home page then these links will go on about us page. and when i will on home page then # tag will work.